# Understanding reactor's FluxProcessor.wrap(upstream, downstream)

Tags: spring, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactor, project-reactor

Processors (Subjects in RxJava) act both as Publishers and Subscribers, so they could subscribe to a Publisher and, in addition, be subscribed so that they pass the values they got from the top Subscriber:

```
Publisher
   |
   \/
 Processor
   |
   \/
Subscriber
```

How does `FluxProcessor.wrap()` fit in this schema? For instance I would like to create a `FluxProcessor` with `FluxProcessor.wrap` that gets values from a `Flux.range()` and can be subscribed to get values.